# FileSystemWatcher Fires Event After Second Change, But Not First

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm having an issue where a file system monitor does not catch the first file added to a folder, but every consequent action fires fine.

The folder I'm watching is on a networked share.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace RTTService
{
    class FileSystemMonitors : IDisposable
    {
        FileSystemWatcher WatchFolder = new FileSystemWatcher();
        public void StartMonitoringDropFolder()
        {
            WatchFolder.Path = @"\\<<NETWORKED SHARE>>\inetpub\mailroot\";
            WatchFolder.NotifyFilter = WatchFolder.NotifyFilter | NotifyFilters.FileName;
            WatchFolder.NotifyFilter = WatchFolder.NotifyFilter | NotifyFilters.Attributes;

            WatchFolder.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(WatchFolder_Action);
            WatchFolder.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(WatchFolder_Action);
            WatchFolder.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(WatchFolder_Action);

            WatchFolder.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


        }

        void WatchFolder_Action(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
            {
                using (Email Email = new Email())
                {
                    Email.ParseInterpretStoreDropFolderForAllMessages(false, false, false);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            WatchFolder.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you log a line containing `e.FullPath` and `e.ChangeType` before the `if (e.ChangeType == ...)`? This behaviour is not reproducible for me. Is it a regular Windows share, or maybe a SaMBa implementation?

Comment: Why are you looking for Changed when you also want Created?

Comment: I switched to using changed instead of created because the created event was never fired when an item was added to the folder. The changed event was, though. Edit: This is a Windows share.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the file exists **before** you create and enable the FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: It is not. I watch the folder using Windows Explorer.